# set different animation while push different view to navigation view in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to set different types of animation for each view that I push to the navigation view.
I had applied animation in the layout of the navigation view but it was applied to all the views of the navigation view.

Here I am adding my view like this and want to set animation here on a particular view.

```
button.up('navigationview').push({
xtype: 'rightPanel',
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tyr this One..

```
 Ext.getCmp('Your Navigation View').getLayout().setAnimation('Which ever animation You want');
```

Following are some animation types.

```
 cube *
 fade
 flip *
 pop
 slide
 swipe *
```

Hope this help . .
Happy Coding

Comment: i tried this code before push my view,but after that i didn't even push my view.

Comment: Can we change the direction of slide? Like from top or right?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the animation of the navigation view each time before pushing the new view.

```
Ext.ComponentManager.get("navigationview").getLayout().setAnimation('fade');
```